# ASP.NET MVC 5- Getting Roles for specfic user

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

In my ASP.NET project I am trying to get a user's current roles by their Id. Here is my code for the controller:

```
 public ActionResult ChangeRole(string id)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id);
        var roles = new RoleManagerViewModel()
        {
            RoleNames = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.Id)
        };
         return View(roles);
    }
```

When I try to run it I get this error however:

> The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.

I read that I can fix that by adding `roleManager enabled="true"`.

After I added that to my `web.config` file, though I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs if the proper authentication is not given through the web.config to the SQL Server being accessed, a typo, or a SQL Server does not exist defined in the connection string to that specific server. If the role manager database is being access, information about doing so might be helpful in the link provided below.

Per example,

```
<add name="SqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MSSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=True;">
</add>
```

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If Windows Authentication is being used then when Integrated Security is set to true it will use Windows Active Directory logon credentials to connect to the database server. Try verifying that logon credentials match was needed to the database server.

Comment: It is just accessing a local database on my computer, so I think I am confused why it's when I try and get the roles I am getting an error.